# Replacing the nth number in a string

Tags: r, regex

I have a set of files which I had named incorrectly. The file name is as follows.

```
Generation_Flux_0_Model_200.txt
Generation_Flux_101_Model_43.txt
Generation_Flux_11_Model_3.txt
```

I need to replace the second number (the model number) by adding 1 to the existing number. So the correct names would be

```
Generation_Flux_0_Model_201.txt
Generation_Flux_101_Model_44.txt
Generation_Flux_11_Model_4.txt
```

This is the code I wrote. I would like to know how to specify the position of the number (replace second number in the string with the new number)?

```
reNameModelNumber <- function(modelName){

  #get the current model number
  modelNumber = as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all(modelName, "\\d+"))[2])

  #increment it by 1
  newModelNumber = modelNumber + 1

  #building the new name with gsub 
  newModelName = gsub("  regex ", newModelNumber, modelName) 

  #rename
  file.rename(modelName, newModelName)


}


reactionModels = list.files(pattern = "^Generation_Flux_\\d+_Model_\\d+.txt$")

sapply(reactionFiles, function(x) reNameModelNumber(x))
```

Comment: Is the number you need to increment is always before the file extension?

Comment: Yes before the file extension

Comment: With `gsubfn`, `gsubfn("\\d+(?=\\.[^.]*$)", ~ as.numeric(x) + 1, reactionFiles, backref=0)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering the question, if you want to increment a certain number inside a string, you may use

```
> library(gsubfn)
> nth = 2
> reactionFiles <- c("Generation_Flux_0_Model_200.txt", "Generation_Flux_101_Model_43.txt", "Generation_Flux_11_Model_3.txt")
> gsubfn(paste0("^((?:\\D*\\d+){", nth-1, "}\\D*)(\\d+)"), function(x,y,z) paste0(x, as.numeric(y) + 1), reactionFiles)
[1] "Generation_Flux_0_Model_201.txt"  "Generation_Flux_101_Model_44.txt" "Generation_Flux_11_Model_4.txt"
```

`nth` here is the number of the digit chunk to increment.

**Pattern details**

- `^((?:\\D*\\d+){n}\\D*)` - Capturing group 1 (the value is accessed in the `gsubfn` method via `x`):

  - `(?:\\D*\\d+){n}` - an *n* occurrences of

    - `\\D*` - 0 or more chars other than digits
    - `\\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `\\D*` - 0+ non-digits
- `(\\d+)` - Capturing group 2 (the value is accessed in the `gsubfn` method via `y`): one or more digits

Comment: Thank you @wiktor for the comprehensive answer. It's useful to have the number position as I have different naming conversions and now it's easy to update.

Answer (score 8):

We can use `gsubfn` to incremement by 1.  Capture the digits (`(\\d+)`)
 followed by a `. and 'txt' at the end (`$`) of the string, and replace it by adding 1 to it

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("(\\d+)\\.txt$", ~ as.numeric(x) + 1, str1)
#[1] "Generation_Flux_0_Model_201"  "Generation_Flux_101_Model_44"
#[3] "Generation_Flux_11_Model_4"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("Generation_Flux_0_Model_200.txt", "Generation_Flux_101_Model_43.txt", 
                   "Generation_Flux_11_Model_3.txt")
```

Answer (score 4):

Using base-R.

```
data <- c( # Just an example
  "Generation_Flux_0_Model_200.txt",
  "Generation_Flux_101_Model_43.txt",
  "Generation_Flux_11_Model_3.txt"
)

fixNameModel <- function(data){
  n <- length(data)

  # get the current model number and increment it by 1
  newn = as.integer(sub(".+_(\\d+)\\.txt", "\\1", data)) + 1L

  #building the new name with gsub
  newModelName <- vector(mode = "character", length = n)
  for (i in 1:n) {
    newModelName[i] <- gsub("\\d+\\.txt$", paste0(newn[i], ".txt"), data[i])
  }
  newModelName
}

fixNameModel(data)
[1] "Generation_Flux_0_Model_201.txt"  "Generation_Flux_101_Model_44.txt"
[3] "Generation_Flux_11_Model_4.txt"
```

You can now do something like `file.rename(modelName, fixNameModel(modelName))`

**EDIT**:

Here is a bit neater version but makes stronger assumptions instead:

```
fixNameModel2 <- function(data) {
  sapply(
    strsplit(data, "_|\\."), 
    function(x) {
      x[5] <- as.integer(x[5]) + 1L
      x <- paste0(x, collapse = "_")
      gsub("_txt", ".txt", x, fixed = TRUE)
    } 
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the digit always occurs before the extension, as is mentioned in the comments, here is another base R solution that is a little bit simpler.

```
sapply(regmatches(tmp, regexec("\\d+(?=\\.)", tmp, perl=TRUE), invert=NA),
       function(x) paste0(c(x[1], as.integer(x[2]) + 1L, x[3]), collapse=""))
```

This returns

```
[1] "Generation_Flux_0_Model_201.txt"  "Generation_Flux_101_Model_44.txt"
[3] "Generation_Flux_11_Model_4.txt"
```

`regexec` with the invert=NA a list of indices where each list element is the index matching the portions of the full with the matched element returned as the second indexed element. `regmatches` takes this information and returns a list of  character vectors that breaks up the original string along the matches. Feed this list to `sapply`, convert the second element to integer and increment. Then paste the result to return an atomic vector.

The regex "\d+(?=\.)" uses a perl look behind, "(?=\.)", looking for the dot without capturing it, but capturing the digits with "\d+".

**data**

```
tmp <- c("Generation_Flux_0_Model_200.txt", "Generation_Flux_101_Model_43.txt", 
"Generation_Flux_11_Model_3.txt")
```